# GPU out of memory when initializing network

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to initialize a CNN and then put it on my GPU for training. When I put it on GPU I get the error: (CUDA error: out of memory). I have run similar networks with no such problems. This is the only thing in cuda as I have not loaded any images as of yet. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

I am using pytorch version 0.4.1 on a GTX 1070ti 8GB.

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.104      Driver Version: 410.104      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P2    39W / 180W |   8024MiB /  8111MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1129      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            36MiB |
|    0      1164      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          57MiB |
|    0      1415      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           200MiB |
|    0      1548      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          90MiB |
|    0      6323      C   /usr/bin/python3                             525MiB |
|    0      9521      C   /usr/bin/python3                            1827MiB |
|    0     18821      C   /usr/bin/python3                            4883MiB |
|    0     27137      G   ...uest-channel-token=16389326112703159917    45MiB |
|    0     29161      C   /usr/bin/python3                             355MiB |
```

I have tried reducing the size of the linear layers with no luck.

```
net = piccnn()
net.to(device)
```

Comment: Do you have any running processes what is the output of nvida-smi? Can you kill anything running?

Comment: I added the output to nvidia-smi

Comment: Maybe try to free up space try a kill -9 1415 and try it. I'm not sure if it'll work Also make sure your GPUs are up to date. I'm no expert with GPU's . Perhaps it could be ram also that needs to be increased

Comment: @JoeA Why would you recommend killing the X server? This is not a good advice! Obviously the processes that eat up the most GPU memory are python interpreters, especially 18821, 9521.

Comment: @Przemek I just wasn't sure why he had two Xorg servers that was my thought process. I'm still learning with GPUs but thank you for correcting me. The python interpreters eat up the most memory I can see that in the output I just wasn't sure if he needed them all.

Comment: Yeah I can see there are two servers which is weird indeed, but killing a randomly selected one - especially if we're not sure what do they do - just doesn't feel like a wise move :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happened to me once when a GPU driver was out of date. My GPU was a 1070 4 gig. I'd recommend a reinstall of drivers and restart.

Comment: I think the only part of this answer that really helped was the restart. From the output of `nvidia-smi` it is clear that there are remains of several processes still occupying memory on the GPU. Killing them would solve the issue, but so would a reboot.

Comment: Hi @NuWaan could you accept my answer if it solved your problem, thank you.